# How to manually create Binding in SapUi5?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have a xml view which should display data from multiple entitytypes (the table only displays the common fields of both types).
Because I want to filter the whole table dynamically I want to setup two bindings manually, filter them when needed and rebuild the corresponding table model after each filtering.

But I don't get my bindings to work properly, i.e. they wont't receive data nor can they get filtered.

in controller.js:

```
this.workOrderBinding = new Binding(this.getView().getModel(), )"/WorkOrderSet"); //Binding is of type sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding
this.issueNoticeBinding = new Binding(this.getView().getModel(), "/IssueNoticeSet"); //Binding is of type sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding

this.workOrderBinding.attachDataReceived(function() {
    var tempModel = new JSONModel();
    tempModel.setData({
        WorkOrderSet: this.workOrderBinding.getModel().getData()
    }, true);
    tempModel.setData({
        WorkOrderSet: this.issueNoticeBinding.getModel().getData()
    }, true);
    this.getView().byId("table").setModel(tempModel);
}, this);
```

where `this.getView().getModel()` returns a global ODataModel defined in manifest.json.

Comment: You should not create and set a new model each time, but rather access the initial one through this.getView().byId("table").getModel(), clear it and affect it new data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [QUnit Test for OData List Binding](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/test/sap/ui/core/qunit/ODataV2ListBinding.qunit.html) there are lots of good examples

Example of doing a list binding manually

```
var oBinding = oModel.bindList("/Categories");

var handler = function() {
  oBinding.detachChange(handler);
}

oBinding.attachChange(handler);
oBinding.initialize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, though it isn't very helpful. It uses a lot of undocumented methods, like `Model.bindList` and strange workarounds. However, if I use `Binding.attachFilter` instead of `attachChange`, the callback gets invoked succesfully, but I am not able to retrieve the filtered data from the binding. `binding.getModel().getProperty("/")` always returns the unfiltered data of the whole model